# git status грязный

Tags: git

когда делаю git status (правлено несколько файлов) и мне вываливает целую кучу подобного:

```
modified:   contents/shop_tpl_var.scss
  modified:   contents/temp/jquery.parallax.js
  modified:   contents/temp/numAnimate.js
  modified:   contents/temp/temp_actions_list.html
  modified:   contents/temp/temp_actions_view.html
```

делаю git pull

```
Already up-to-date.
```

делаю git diff 
 по файлам которые не редажились (ето имейджи но и с текстовыми такое же) выбивает такую белиберду.

```
diff --git a/_images/ajax-loader2.gif b/_images/ajax-loader2.gif
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
diff --git a/_images/be-dealer.jpg b/_images/be-dealer.jpg
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
diff --git a/_images/blank.png b/_images/blank.png
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

Вопрос: как мне отслеживать какие я файлы поправил и которые находятся в modified по причине что я их редажил? Спасибо

Comment: Не совсем понял вывод диффа. Поменялись права у файлов?

Comment: делать git pull, пока есть незакоммиченные данные - плохо. А после этого все вышеуказанные проблемы пропадают.

Comment: @KoVadim, не совсе ясно, о чём вы говорите. какие именно проблемы пропадают и после чего именно?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin видимо, после коммита.

Comment: проблема с пониманием, кем был модифицирован файл. Если сделать коммит, то не будет "модифицированных файлов, и если с pull они снова появились, то значит это проблемы pull (но они там появляться только если был конфликт или кто то перестарался ручками).

Comment: @KoVadim исключение если настроен авто-стэш (stash). В остально согласен.

Comment: если человек настроил себе автостэш, то подобных вопросов уже бы не задавал (исключение - начитался "туториалов").

Comment: убили слова "редажились" и "имейджи"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все файлы, про которые `git diff` пишет, что они модифицированы, на самом деле модифицированы.

у указанных файлов вы изменили права. насколько я вижу, добавили биты выполнимости для пользователя, группы и всех остальных.

возможно, вы сделали это не самостоятельно, а права изменила какая-то программа/скрипт, которую вы запускали. если это происходит регулярно, но определить эту программу и исправить её поведение не удастся, возможно, имеет смысл сохранить эти изменения прав в репозитории (хотя сами по себе в данном случае они абсолютно бессмысленны).

«откатить» же эти изменения можно так:

```
$ git checkout файл1 файл2 ...
```

Comment: >  (хотя сами по себе они абсолютно бессмысленны).

ну я бы не сказал, что права доступа бессмысленны.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо, я добавил уточнение: «в данном случае».

Comment: А я бы задумался. Если картинка стала исполняемой, значит либо кто то обновил ее под виндой, либо может там не совсем картинка:)

Comment: спасибо, действительно был "прикол что менялись права"